# How to remove exta element around the constants added in react 15.0.2

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactjs 15.0.2, but when I add constants in render it keeps adding extra elements around it like below. I want clean html from it.

React output is as below:

```
<p data-reactid="49">
    <!-- react-text: 50 -->Join the
        <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 51 -->Hello 1<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 52 -->Testing
    <!-- /react-text -->     
</p>
```

Code is as below:

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
render() {
const text1 = 'Hello 1';
return (
    <p>Join the {text1} Tesing</p>)
}
}
```

for server to send html in node I am using code as below:

```
res.send(`<!doctype html>
  ${ReactDOM.renderToString(<Html assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} store={store} />)}`);
```

I want clean html here as Join the "Hello 1 Testing"

Answer (score 0):

These comments and `data-reactid`s are used by React internally to update the text when props/state change. When rendering to static markup you obviously don't need them, because no further changes will happen after the HTML has been sent to the browser.

Fortunately there is `renderToStaticMarkup` method in `react-dom/server` which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
  /* ... */
res.send(`<!doctype html>
  ${ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Html 
      assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} 
      store={store} 
  />)}`);
```

Comment: I tried renderToStaticMarkup but is giving same output

Comment: I am fine with data-reactid, but I dont need <!-- react-text: 51 --> these react-text elements